# A problem on compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

let $(e_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ be orthonormal basis in hilbert space $H$ and $T\in B(H)$ and is compact operator.

For any $N\in \mathbb{N},$ let $H(N)$ is closed subspace generated by $\{e_j:j\geq N\}$ .

show  that given any $\epsilon >0 \ $ there exist an $N$  such that for all $h\in H(N)$ $$||T(h)||\ \leq \epsilon ||h||$$

i was thinking of what property of compact operator can i use here. any hint please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the property does not hold. That means that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $n$ there exists an $h_n'\in H(n)$ with $\|h'\|=1$ and $\|Th'\|>\varepsilon$.

Now choose $h_1'\in H(1)$ with $\|h'_1\|=1$ and $\|Th'\|>\varepsilon$. By erasing "the end" of $h_1'$ and renormalizing we obtain $h_1\in\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_{n_1}\}$ with $\|h_1\|=1$ and $\|Th_1\|>\varepsilon/2$.

Then there exists $h_2'\in H(n_1+1)$ with $\|h_2'\|=1$ and $\|Th_2'\|>\varepsilon$. As above we obtain $h_2\in\operatorname{span}\{e_{n_1+1},\ldots,e_{n_2}\}$ with $\|h_2\|=1$ and $\|Th_2\}>\varepsilon/2$.

Continuing in the same fashion, we get a sequence $\{h_k\}$ with $\|h_k\|=1$, $\|Th_k\|>\varepsilon/2$ and, more importantly, $h_j\perp h_k$ whenever $j\ne k$.

But the above is a contradiction: since $T$ is compact, the bounded sequence $\{Th_n\}$ admits a convergent subsequence, $Th_{n_j}\to y$. As this is norm convergence, we get $\|y\|>\varepsilon/2$. We also have that $h_n\to0$ weakly; then, for any $x$, 
$$
\langle Th_n,x\rangle=\langle h_n,T^*x\rangle\to0. 
$$
So $Th_n\to0$ weakly. In particular, $Th_{n_j}\to0$; this would imply $y=0$, but we already know that $\|y\|\geq\varepsilon/2$.

The contradiction shows that the property holds.